# AWSインスタンスストアボリュームのディスクの初期化 SSD RAID0 CENTOS7

Tags: aws, raid

AWS EC2 C3を利用しています。インスタンスストアボリュームをEC2インスタンス作成時に追加しました。それには初期化が必要の対象でした。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

> 特定のインスタンスにアタッチされたボリュームは、**初期化されないと初回書き込みペナルティ**を受けます。インスタンスストアボリュームの初期化の詳細については、「インスタンスストアボリュームのディスクパフォーマンスの最適化」を参照してください。

ペナルティを受けるとのことなので初期化をしています、8時間以上かかるそうです。

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M|tee /dev/sdb|tee /dev/sdc|tee /dev/sde > /dev/sdd
```

その後RAID0にしようと思っているのですが、下記内容の意味がわかりません。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/disk-performance.html

> ドライブを RAID 用に構成すると、**ドライブのすべての場所に書き込みを行う**ことで、ドライブが初期化されます。ソフトウェアベースの RAID を構成するときは、再構築の最低速度を必ず変更してください。

RAID0はこちらを参考にしようと思っています。

[EC2でインスタンスストアをRAID0で組む手順/起動スクリプト化 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/shiru/items/c765accff6d3c5f8ea34)

> ```
> yum install mdadm
> yes Y | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/xvd[bc]
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
> mkdir -p /media/ephemeral0
> mount -o rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered /dev/md0 /media/ephemeral0
> ```

手順としては上記dd if=を実行し終わったあとに、QiitaのRAID0をすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ドライブのすべての場所に書き込みを行うことで、ドライブが初期化されます。

これは`mdmadm --create` を実行するとRAIDの初期化が始まるのですが、その際、ドライブのすべての場所に書き込みが行われます。そのため、完了するまで非常に時間がかかります。これを一般的にリビルド(再構築)と言いいます。

> ソフトウェアベースの RAID を構成するときは、再構築の最低速度を必ず変更してください。

LinuxのソフトウェアRAIDの場合、カーネルパラメータでリビルドの処理速度が制限されるため、
デフォルトの値だと、リビルドに大変な時間がかかってしまう可能性があります。ドキュメントには、次のコマンドで 制限を緩和するようにという注意事項が書かれています。

```
echo $((30*1024)) > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
```

> 手順としては上記dd if=を実行し終わったあとに、QiitaのRAID0をすれば良いですか？

試してないですが こんな感じじゃないでしょうか。

1. /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min の値を変更
2. dd if=... を実行
3. あとは Qiita の記事と同じ

   echo $((30*1024)) > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
   dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M|tee /dev/sdb|tee /dev/sdc|tee /dev/sde > /dev/sdd
   yum install mdadm
   yes Y | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/xvd[bc]
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
   mkdir -p /media/ephemeral0
   mount -o rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered /dev/md0 /media/ephemeral0

チューニングの話なので 実際に試して見ないとわかりませんが RAIDのリビルドでディスクの全書き込みが行われますので dd if=... は不要な気もします。